# Flipped NSImage in the NSCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscell

Why NSImage drawn flipped in the NSCell of NSTableView. And how proper fix that behavior. I returns image from the data source method:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
return [NSImage imageNamed: @"test.png"];
}
```

As workaround I tried:

```
[NSImage setFlipped:NO];
```

All is ok but as documentation says that it deprecated method

osx 10.7-10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by replacing code of getting image from:

```
return [NSImage imageNamed: @"test.png"];
```

to:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForImageResource: test.png]];
return [[NSImage alloc] initWithDataIgnoringOrientation:imageData];
```

I don't know reason of that behavior and documentation nothing says me. But I'll happy if you explain me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1285771) is some info I just came across.

Basically according to the link you have to:

1. Drag an image cell in the column you wish to show the image
2. Return an NSImageCell initialised with your image, like so:

   ```
   - (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row 
   {
       NSCell *imageCell = [[NSCell alloc] initImageCell:[NSImage imageNamed: @"test.png"]];
       return imageCell;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you but I get crash with you way. With my way all is ok but image flipped.